# Unable to get mutable Windows environment variable map flutter project android studio

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart

`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Unable to get mutable Windows environment variable map
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
  `

this error showing when debgging..

how to solve this lastly updated gradle version